# Pause program when certain key is pressed

Tags: python, pyautogui

Hi I have a program that spams people messages but it can get out of hand because I don't have a way of easily pausing my program.

I need help with pausing the programming when key \ is pressed?

```
import pyautogui
import time


numLines = 1
finished = False

while True:
    if finished == True:
        playAgain = input('Would you like to run this program again? ')
        if playAgain == 'no' or playAgain == 'No':
            break
        elif playAgain == 'Yes' or playAgain == 'yes':
            print('Have fun :)')
        else:
            print('Please try again - Invalid input')
    while True:
        whichScript = input('Please enter the name of the script you want to view: ')
        linesOrSend = input('Do you want to see the numer of lines or send: ')
        if linesOrSend == 'send' or linesOrSend == 'Send':
            time.sleep(5)
            check = input('Are you sure? ')
            if check == 'yes' or check == 'Yes':
                time.sleep(10)
                f = open(whichScript, "r")
                for word in f:
                    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
                    pyautogui.press('enter')
                finished = True
                break
            else:
                break
        elif linesOrSend == 'Lines' or linesOrSend == 'lines':
            f = open(whichScript, "r")
            for word in f:
                numLines += 1
            print(numLines)
            finished = True
            break
        else:
            print('Please try again - Invalid input')
```

Comment: Are you ware of KeyboardInterrupt?

Comment: A suggestion on your code: Use the `lower` method on the user input to only check once. In addition, it will function if the user types "YES" or "yEs", or any other combination that composes of the letters Y, E, and S. To do it: `if variablename.lower() == 'what you want':`. Make sure it is all lowercase though, otherwise, it will never evaluate as true.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a keyboard module with many features. Install it, perhaps with this command:

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

Then use it in code like:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break  # finishing the loop
    except:
        break  # if user pressed a key other than the given key the loop will break
```

Comment: Sadly I can't use this because I'm not an administrator on my mac and it doesnt let me

Comment: On Win10 & anaconda, you can download from pypi, and install without being a superuser. It'll install into your user ProgramData area. Not sure if iOS or whatever Jobs' mob uses these days has an equivalent?

Comment: Nah i don't think so. Thanks though!